# Cannot use import statement outside a module React.js when trying to start the project?

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot, react-native, module

I am dealing with an error when I try to start a newly created React project with SpringBoot. When I run npm start I get the following error:

```
   npm start

> project@1.0.0 start C:\Users\Project - \Project
> node frontend/src/app.js

(node:22180) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
C:\Users\X - \project\frontend\src\app.js:1
import logo from './logo.svg';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! project@1.0.0 start: `node frontend/src/app.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the project@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

As for the warning, I added the "type": "module" into the package.json file but it still remains.

Package.json:

```
    {
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "Jest",
    "start": "node frontend/src/app.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "only": "0.0.2",
    "react-cookie": "^4.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "reactstrap": "^8.10.0"
  }
}
```

App.js:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

So for some reason the import statement is triggering this error because it is outside a module? But I set the app.js type to module and it didn't do anything. I am really confused.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: can you try to add `node --experimental-modules frontend/src/app.js` flag in your start command.

Comment: @PradipDhakal I tried: npm start node --experimental-modules frontend/src/app.js and got the same error, thanks